# Answer deleted by a moderator despite being correct?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just came up upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8095242/507519) and I noticed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095242/cant-execute-bash-scripts-even-as-root/8095280#8095280), which has been deleted by a moderator. According to the comments in the question, this is actually the correct answer that was initially posted as a comment and then as an answer after an explicit request by the question owner.

Why was this post deleted? Sure, it *is* short, but that is apparently in the *"short and to the point"* sense.

Comment: It would definitely be preferable not to phrase answers in the form of a question, but I restored the post.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Ah, I flagged it for moderator attention - by the time I clicked Flag, it had already been undeleted :-). You have my thanks, and (I presume) the thanks of its owner...

Comment: We are just that fast at processing flags these days.  :)

Comment: Woot! Not me!  Didn't do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was likely flagged as "Not an answer" and then converted to a comment, because it was formulated as a contra-question instead of a real answer. If you put your mouse above the time, you'll see the exact timestamp in a tooltip. Now, the OP has commented back that this was indeed the right answer and requested him to repost it as an answer. But this happened *after* the moderator has converted the answer.

There are at least 2 options:

1. The answerer has to repost it as an answer again.
2. The answerer (or someone else) has to flag the question and request for an undelete.

Either way, the answer should be edited to represent a real answer. For example,

> That can happen if you have mounted the file system with `noexec` option, you should remove this option.

Comment: +1 I had not noticed the timestamp tooltips!

Comment: IMO the answer should be undeleted, as I believe that the deletion may have been a bit hasty. Unfortunately I cannot do that myself...

Comment: Stack Overflow is *full* of very helpful tooltips. Go find them out. As to the undelete, this isn't possible if a moderator has deleted it. Only a moderator can undelete it. You could try flagging the question and request for undelete.

Comment: Ah, I flagged it for moderator attention - by the time I clicked *Flag*, it had already been undeleted :-)